# How do I make some TCP ports accessible internal only?

Tags: server, python, proxy, nginx

I am running four instances of Tornado app at ports 9000 - 9003. I use Nginx as load balancer at the front. However user can access these ports also, for example mysite:9000 is also accessible.

so how do I disable external access and make it accessible only to nginx?

Here is my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` contents:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 5;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll; 
}

http{

    proxy_next_upstream error;

    upstream tornadoes { 
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
        server 127.0.0.1:9001;
        server 127.0.0.1:9002;
        server 127.0.0.1:9003;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;  

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    keepalive_timeout 65;
    proxy_read_timeout 200;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css text/xml application/x-javascript application/xml application/atom+xml text/javascript;


    server { 
        listen 80;
        server_name example.in www.example.in;

        location /static/ {
            root /home/magneto/torapp; 
            if ($query_string) {
                expires max; 
            }
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass_header Server; 
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host; 
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme; 
            proxy_pass http://tornadoes;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something you cannot fullfill. If you decide to communicate via TCP between nginx and your application, localhost will always be able to access the ports -- this is the way, nginx is doing it.

You could reconfiure it to use sockets, but this something needs to be done starting by your applciation nginx is the reverse proxy for.